# C# json object with empty json array

Tags: c#, json

I have a returned json object that contains an empty json array

```
{[]}
```

EDIT:

How do I check this in an if statement?

```
        string arrayData = string.Empty;

        if (response.Contains("\"data\":"))
        {
            JToken root = JObject.Parse(response);
            JToken data = root["data"];
            if (data != null)
            {
                arrayData = data.ToString();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            arrayData = response;
        }

        var responseDatas = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(arrayData);
```

Here, responseDatas is now

```
{[]}
```

Comment: I don't think it's a valid json string.

Comment: I am sure it is not ;) @DannyChen

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First, that is invalid JSON. The array should have a name, like this:

```
{ list: [] }
```

Second, you can deserialize the JSON using JSON.NET and then test the result:

```
public class ClassWithList
{
    public List<object> list { get; set; }
}

var o = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ClassWithList>(json);

if (o.list != null && o.list.Count > 0)
{ }
```

Comment: thanks! exactly what I needed, checking o.list.Count is the solution. I love stackoverflow... :)

Comment: Its really helpful for me. Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

The json is invalid (in the original question and in the accepted answer).  You should include double quotes ...

```
{
    "list": []
}
```